# Making multiple API requests, updating dataframe -python

Tags: python, dataframe, api

I Would like to make a request every minute throughout the day, and would like to append this information to a dataframe

I would like to be able to access this dataframe

Could you please point me to certain modules to use.

I tried using schedule, but i can't seem to access the dataframe as it is running.

Comment: You should rather use a database (e.g. Postgresql) and use python to append to a table there...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a [`threading.Timer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#timer-objects) is what you're looking for.

```py
import threading

def my_updating_function(df, request_args):
    ...  # homework for the asker

t = threading.Timer(
    60,
    my_updating_function,
    args=(df, request_args),
)
t.start()
```

Note your design may cause trouble if this is within a web API

Comment: Thank you for your response, I shall check it out